# Port Forwarding Not Working On Virtual Box v6.1 Even on seperate computer

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, portforwarding

So I've been having trouble with port forwarding for my virtual box (Specifically Version 6.1) lately, I went so far as to go out and spend $180 on a new router but still nothing! I've been having this problem for weeks now and I'm slowly narrowing down the issue, It cant be my router since. You know.. Bought a new one.. So then I thought it was just Kali Linux so I tried Parrot OS and nothing, I tried BackBox6 and nothing, I tried BlackArch Linux and nothing! So it can't be the operating system, then I thought it was my laptop, I have the ASUS ROG Strix G731GT With a core i7 9th running a GTX 1650ti Graphics Card on Windows 10, I got it fixed like two months ago due to Networking issues not really related to this and after I got it back port forwarding worked for a bit then all of a sudden bloop! It stopped, I have no idea what could of caused it, I decided to use ngrok for port forwarding and that worked.. Till it didn't! That stopped working all of a sudden! at this point I thought it was my computer so I got my old school laptop (Which surprisingly ran Linux fine) and set that all up and I connected my main laptop to a hotspot, and lord and behold!... It didn't work... Nowww I got to thinking... Could it be my Virtual Box? I Don't know, I'm currently testing each and every version of Oracle VM Virtual Box right now to see if its the issue, I remember I asked a questions before about my Virtual Box not working when copying text from my host computer to the Virtual Machine and someone replied saying the version I had was a bit buggy and didn't work well and he gave me a link to a different version and it worked, this was at the time that ngrok still worked and port forwarding didn't I didn't actually test to see if port forwarding works though, now i cant find that question, he said something about guest additions I don't know, please if you know anything at all that can help me feel free to let me know and if you have any questions about my hardware or software feel free to ask I'll be refreshing my page very often lol, also if you decide to leave a comment saying this question cannot be posted how about you instead forward me to somewhere that allows these types of questions, that would be helpful -_-. Thanks.